# Comparing Key items with an integer using Hasmap in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the Key item to see if is equal to the integer that is in the Translate constructor. But someone I can't really figure it out. Sorry for the mess and I' still fairly new to Java. Thanks

```
public class Translate {
    
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        private int number;

        map.put(0, "zero");
        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        map.put(3, "three");
        map.put(4, "four");
        map.put(5, "five");
        map.put(6, "six");
        map.put(7, "seven");
        map.put(8, "eight");
        map.put(9, "nine");
    
        public Translate(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    
        //this is where I'm stuck. I need to compare the Key item to see if is it equal to the integer that is in the Translate constructor. 
        public String convertToString() {
            if (map.get(number) == this.number) {
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either make a function that will put the data inside the map, then call that function just before calling convert to string. Another way to do it is to put that inside a static block

Comment: So either your number is or isn't in the hashmap as a key. If it is, ```map.containsKey(number)``` will return true. If not, it will return false.

Answer (score 2):

You have to try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Translate {
    
    private static Map<Integer, String> map;
    
    static {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(0, "zero");
        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        map.put(3, "three");
        map.put(4, "four");
        map.put(5, "five");
        map.put(6, "six");
        map.put(7, "seven");
        map.put(8, "eight");
        map.put(9, "nine");
    }
        
    private int number;
    
    public Translate(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
    public String convertToString() {
        if (map.containsKey(this.number)) {
            return map.get(this.number);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Translate t = new Translate(7);
        System.out.println(t.convertToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the expert on java but here is what i found troublesome

if (map.get(number).equals(this.number)) <--- 1.you are fetching the value not the key in this.

Instead check  with  map.contains() , if returned true by it, return the value of the key you passed.

2. You should never compare objects with "==" but should instead use .equals() method of that collection , if it is there.

PS: Open for feedback if I wrote something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```java
public String convertToString() {
  // You just need to see if the map contains this key, so you can use containsKey
  if (map.containsKey(this.number)) {
    // Do whatever else you want to do
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you will use the value in the map if it exists, you can skip the `containsKey` and just go straight to `get`

```java
public String convertToString() {
  // Return either the value in the map with key of this.number, or a message that 
  // indicates that no value is present
  return map.getOrDefault(this.number, "Couldn't find " + this.number + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Translate` method with any value at first. Or, you can give default value to number, such as `int number =5;`

Then you can use

```
public String convertToString() {
    if (map.containsKey(this.number)) {
        return map.get(this.number);
    }
    return null;
} method.
```

Then, print the value  `System.out.println(t.convertToString());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Translate {

    private int number;

    Map<Integer, String> map = Map.of(0, "zero", 1, "one", 2, "two", 3, "three", 4, "four", 5, "five", 6, "six", 7, "seven", 8, "eight", 9, "nine");

    public Translate(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String convertToString() {
        return map.get(number);  // returns null if there's no entry
    }
}
```

Theabove code rerurns `null` if there's no entry for the number. Alternatively, you could just return the number itself.

```
public String convertToString() {
    return map.getOrDefault(number, Integer.toString(number));
}
```

If you wanted to be strict, you could throw an exception if an invalid number is passed to the constructor:

```
public Translate(int number) {
    if (!map.containsKey(number)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("number must be 0-9");
    }
    this.number = number;
}
```